# How can I use WiX properties in a sql file executed from the installer?

Tags: wix

I have a WiX install project that I am rewriting based on our previous installers from Wise.  In Wise, you can add files for it to execute (ours used sql script files) and it had a replace tab that specified certain text in the file to be replaced with either with static text or a Wise property.

I am wondering if this is possible in WiX?

Example:

```
use [SQLDBNAME]
SELECT *
FROM Employee
```

Where WiX would read the file and replace the `[SQLDBNAME]` with the value set in WiX's properties table?

Answer (score 7):

The Property replacement works for [SqlString](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/sql_xsd_sqlstring.htm) element, where you define the SQL string literally as a value of the attribute. However, it doesn't work for [SqlScript](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/sql_xsd_sqlscript.htm) element, where you put the entire SQL script file to Binary. It all depends on how complex is your SQL queries.

When using SqlString, don't forget that SQL uses `[` and `]` to escape its own reserved words. So you should escape the MSI properties like this in that case: `[\[]` and `[\]]`.

Hope this helps.